# Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.size()" because "misVideos" is null

Tags: java, array, tomcat, servlets, null

Hola e decidió reformula esta pregunta.

Tambien grabe un video para que se puedan ver el problema si no me e expresado adecuadamente:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9i6RGaKKV2ci6f9KTWzTDTl1kcINAeO/view?usp=sharing

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un Array "misVideos" en el cual estoy guardando información de videos musicales a la vez que empleo un servlet donde también hay 2 métodos encargados de guardar y cargar la información registrada por medio de un archivo serializado, sin embargo, parece que la función de cargar el archivo solo se da cuando añado un nuevo video porque si intento acceder a la pagina encargada del listado de videos desde mi index obtengo este error (La pagina "Listar videos" es la misma que debe abrirse desde el index):

```
Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error


Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/listarVideos.jsp] en línea [22]

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/listarVideos.jsp] en línea [22]

19:             ArrayList<Video> misVideos = (ArrayList<Video>) request.getAttribute("misVideos");
20:             // Verificar si misVideos no es nulo antes de iterar sobre él
21:             
22:                  System.out.println("Se cargaron " + misVideos.size() + " videos exitosamente.");
23:                 for (Video v : misVideos) {
24:                     out.print("IdVideo:" + v.getIdVideo() + "<br>");
25:                     out.print("Titulo:" + v.getTitulo() + "<br>");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


causa raíz
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.size()" because "misVideos" is null
    org.apache.jsp.listarVideos_jsp._jspService(listarVideos_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.
```

Este es el código de mi Servet

```
package servlets;

import com.umariana.mundo.Video;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


@WebServlet(name = "SvVideo", urlPatterns = {"/SvVideo"})
public class SvVideo extends HttpServlet {
    ArrayList<Video> misVideos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        // Asegúrate de obtener el ServletContext correctamente
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        
        // Cargar los videos serializados al iniciar la aplicación
        cargarVideosDesdeArchivo(servletContext);
    }
    


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Aquí vienen los datos por doPost
        // Manda las variables por debajo del bus
        String idVideo = request.getParameter("idVideo");
        String titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
        String autor = request.getParameter("autor");
        String anio = request.getParameter("anio");
        String url = request.getParameter("url");
        String categoria = request.getParameter("categoria");
        String letra = request.getParameter("letra");   

        try {
            int idVideoInt = Integer.parseInt(idVideo);
            // Ingresar datos al objeto
            Video miVideo = new Video(idVideoInt, titulo, autor, anio, categoria, url, letra);
            misVideos.add(miVideo);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Manejo de la excepción si idVideo no es un número válido
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error al convertir idVideo a entero: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Guardar la lista de videos en un archivo
        guardarVideosEnArchivo();

        // Agregar el ArrayList al objeto de solicitud
        request.setAttribute("misVideos", misVideos);

        // Redireccionar a la página web destino
        request.getRequestDispatcher("listarVideos.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


    // Método para guardar la lista de videos en un archivo
    private void guardarVideosEnArchivo() {
        try {
            // Obtener la ruta real de la carpeta "data" en el proyecto web
            String dataPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/data");

            // Verificar si la carpeta "data" existe, si no, crearla
            File dataFolder = new File(dataPath);
            if (!dataFolder.exists()) {
                dataFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            // Crear un archivo para guardar o reescribir la lista de videos serializada
            String filePath = dataPath + File.separator + "videos.ser";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(misVideos);
            oos.close();
            System.out.println("Datos de videos guardados exitosamente en: " + filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error al guardar los datos de videos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    // Método para cargar los videos desde el archivo
    private void cargarVideosDesdeArchivo(ServletContext servletContext) {
        try {
            // Obtener la ruta real del archivo de datos
            String dataPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/data/videos.ser");
            
            // Verificar si el archivo existe
            File archivo = new File(dataPath);
            if (archivo.exists()) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                misVideos  = (ArrayList<Video>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                System.out.println("Datos de videos cargados exitosamente desde: " + dataPath);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error al cargar los datos de videos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Y este e el codigo de la pagina que debe presentar la informacion:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.umariana.mundo.Video"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Listar videos</h1>
        <a href="index.jsp">Volver al inicio</a>
        
        
        
        <%
            // Obtener array list de la solicitud
            ArrayList<Video> misVideos = (ArrayList<Video>) request.getAttribute("misVideos");
            // Verificar si misVideos no es nulo antes de iterar sobre él
            
                 System.out.println("Se cargaron " + misVideos.size() + " videos exitosamente.");
                for (Video v : misVideos) {
                    out.print("IdVideo:" + v.getIdVideo() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Titulo:" + v.getTitulo() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Autor;" + v.getAutor() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Anio:" + v.getAnio() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Categoria:" + v.getCategoria() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Url" + v.getUrl() + "<br>");
                    out.print("Letra:" + v.getLetra() + "<br>");
                    out.print("------------------------------------------------------------"+"<br>");
                }
             
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Agreadezco su colaboracion

Comment: Olvide mencionarlo estoy trabajando con NetBeans

Comment: Si invocas directamente la página JSP de listar videos, el request no tiene el atributo que estás buscando, es nulo, de ahí que te dé ese error. Tienes muchas opciones. Una puede ser copiar el código que lee videos en la página que lista. Otra es pasar siempre por el servlet que lee y redirige al listado.

Comment: Millones de gracias :) @RubioRic tienes toda la razón